# ¿Cómo puedo utilizar una nueva función en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Me encuentro aprendiendo como utilizar Laravel pero tengo una duda, en mi controlador de Usuarios tengo un método para paginar en la función index para así mostrar solo una parte de todos los registros de la base de datos:

```
public function index()
    {
        $users = User::paginate(10);
        return view('user.index', compact('users'));
    }
```

Lo que quiero agregar es un método para ordenar los registros mostrados (cosa que ya encontré):

```
public function indexOrder()
    {
        $users = User::orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')->get();
        return view('user.index', compact('users'));
    }
```

Pero no puedo hacer que la vista index tome esa función, y si utilizo el método User::orderBy en la función index no funciona ya que solo toma uno de los métodos y no los dos, ¿alguna ayuda?

Comment: Querés devolver todos los registros paginados Y ordenados? Y/o querés poder ordenar la tabla que estás mostrando (asumo) de manera ascendente y descendente al clickear en algún lado?

Comment: Ambos me valen ya que es un proyecto de prueba, pero quisiera sabes como ordenarlos haciendo click en algún lado, ya que la función que tengo solo los ordena directamente desde el código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar ambos métodos para ordenar y luego paginar:

```php
public function index()
{
   $users = User::orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')->paginate(10);
   return view('user.index', compact('users'));
}
```

Ref: [Paginating Query Builder Results](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, tenia la duda de como se colocaban ambos métodos en una sola función, en caso de agregar otro método ¿lo colocaría igualmente con -> ?

Comment: Si, pero probablemente antes del `->paginate(10)`.